# Storing data into AWS Aurora Mysql through Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-aurora

I want to run Lambda once daily which would query third-party API and returned data needs to be stored in Aurora MySQL database. Is it even possible to save data in Aurora directly through Lambda. After reading docs, the only way possible is via text files saved in S3 which is also through command line Interface using `LOAD DATA FROM S3` statement and not through AWS SDK or API call.. Is that so or Am I missing something? Is there any way I can achieve desired results Lambda--->Aurora through SDK or API calls.

Thanks in advance. Pardon me if I am sounding silly

Comment: Have you seen this example? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-rds-tutorial.html

Comment: hmm.. thanks for sharing the link. I was in impression that Aurora DB is different than usual MySQL or Postgresql and hence different ways to connect to Aurora...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at RDS Proxy: https://aws.amazon.com/rds/proxy/. This should allow you to interact.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It looks like can solve the problem

Comment: Glad I helped :)